# Create css-file in Webpack 2

Tags: webpack

I'm working on a `webpack-config` where I want to export out my sass file as i .css-file to "static/css", as I do with the js. I cant get it to work. This is what my webpack looks like:

```javascript
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
const config = {
devtool: '#eval-source-map',
entry: './src/js/index.js',
output: {
    filename: isProd ? '[name].[chunkhash].js' : '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/js')
},
module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'buble-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
            objectAssign: 'Object.assign'
        }
    }, 
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-
        loader'])
    }]
}
}

if (isProd) {
    config.devtool = '#source-map'
    config.plugins.push(
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: true
        })
    )
}

module.exports = config
```

Answer (score -1):

you can take a look at it, i think it will help
https://devforgalaxy.github.io/en/2017/11/09/webpack-complie-scss-into-css-en.html

for bundling js
https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/modern-approach-of-javascript-bundling-with-webpack-3b7b3e5f4e7

Comment: you can use babel-loader to bundle javascript

Comment: Can you provide a proper example where it gets implemented in my current code? Wich was the question.